# RequireJS module declarations in TypeScript

Tags: requirejs, typescript

I've recently updated to TypeScript 0.9.5 which is now throwing up new errors during compilation.

I'm defining an AMD module using RequireJS as outlined [HERE](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename).

```
define('myModule', [
    'angular',
    'config'
    ], function (angular, config) {
        'use strict';

        ...
});
```

The TypeScript definition file for RequireJS has the following definition for `RequireDefine`:

```
/**
* Define a module with a name and dependencies.
* @param name The name of the module.
* @param deps List of dependencies module IDs.
* @param ready Callback function when the dependencies are loaded.
*   callback deps module dependencies
*   callback return module definition
**/
(name: string, deps: string[], ready: (...deps: any[]) => any): void;
```

However I'm getting the following errors:

```
error TS2082: Build: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
error TS2087: Build: Could not select overload for 'call' expression.
```

The intellisense error states:

*Call signatures of types '(angular:any, config:any) => any' and '(...deps: any[]) => any' are incompatible.*

Is the definition file incorrect? Where am I going wrong with the callback parameters?

***Further Information:***

Changing the declaration to the following now compiles.

```
define('myModule', [
    'angular',
    'config'
    ], function (...args:any[]) {
        'use strict';

        ...
});
```

However moving to a single parameter object is surely a backwards step? Is this a limitation of the definition file or the TypeScript compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a limitation of the definition file or the TypeScript compiler?

It's **both**. It's a "limitation" of the TypeScript compiler (limitation is quoted since it is enforcing a valid constraint here), and can be fixed from the definition file.

It's actually a lot simpler to reproduce this case:

```
function argLoving(fn: (...deps: any[]) => any){

}

argLoving(function(x,y){ // <- compile error

});
```

The issue is - while you can *call* the function in argLoving with `x` and `y` when you declare or supply it - it has to actually accept varargs to not break type safety.

Imagine the following:

```
function argLoving(fn: (...deps: any[]) => any){

}
function foo(x:any,y:any){

}
argLoving(foo);
```

Now it's *clear* that `argLoving` is accepting a function that works on a variable number of arguments but foo only works on exactly two.

That's the type problem.

The way C# solves this is pretty ugly* (with `Func` for example), so if you're looking for a quick& dirty fix - what you can do is just define multiple signatures in your `.d.ts` file:

This of course compiles with no problem:

```
function argLoving(fn: (x:any) => any)
function argLoving(fn: (x:any,y:any) => any)
function argLoving(fn: (x:any,y:any,z:any) => any)
function argLoving(fn: (x:any,y:any,z:any,a:any) => any)
function argLoving(fn: (...deps: any[]) => any){

}
function foo(x:any,y:any){

}
argLoving(foo); // this compiles now
```

<sup>* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx - look at all the `Action` and `Func` overloads in the left</sup>

---

**Update:**

After I opened an issue on GitHub - the author of DefinitelyTyped put pull request and for this issue using the same fix suggested here https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/1434 . It's being discussed here https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/1435

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, much clearer now. However I'm not sure your suggested fix can really be applied to the RequireJS definition file. Imposing an upper limit on the number of parameters a method takes is acceptable (if you have > x you're doing something wrong). Putting a limit on the number of 'dependencies' a module may require could be more difficult to justify, considering modularization is now encouraged.

Comment: @BrettPostin You're right, What you'd really want to say though is that the first array passed needs to have the same length as the varargs the function gets with a constraint. That's the actual constraint here and you can't express that in TypeScript (yet). Still, C# does `Func` and `Action` with 1 to 31 arguments for quite a while now, they're both use extensively and the complaint level is pretty low. Do you actually have any modules with more than 31 constraints? Like I said - I agree that it's problematic, but it's also very practical imo.

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem for us, but as the definition file is a community driven project maybe someone in the RequireJS world would! I'm going to file it as an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/requirejs).

Comment: @BrettPostin I Already did :) https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/1434

Answer (score 1):

For function definitions that take anything and return anything the new recommended syntax is :

```
function require(fn: Function){

}
```